# "Exists X | P(X)" holds but for no X does P(X) hold

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Is there a known case in any classical logic rich enough to obey the Incompleteness Theorem in which:

$$\exists x \space | \space P(x) $$

yet at the same time:

$$\forall x \space \not \exists G \space | \space Proof(G, P(x))$$

where $Proof(G, P)$ is the relation that $G$ is a proof of $P$ ?

Comment: Are you talking about statements that are theorems or statements that are true in some particular model?  If you want these to be theorems then you're in trouble because the second statement implies the theory is consistent and by Gödel it can't prove its own consistency unless it is inconsistent.

Comment: I'm talking about statements that are theorems.  Read closely - the second statement requires there /not/ be a proof of P(x) for any particular x, in spite of $\exists x P(x)$.

Comment: Proof from *what*? The incompleteness theorem is about *theories* and your question is about *logics*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear, but the following observation shows that the answer is **yes** according to all interpretations I can come up with *(in particular, I think by "logic" you mean "theory")*:

> There is a consistent recursively axiomatizable theory $T$ containing PA, and a formula $\varphi$ in the language of $T$, such that $T\vdash\exists x\varphi(x)$ but for each term $t$ in the language of $T$ do we have $T\vdash\neg \varphi(t)$.

*Proof*: Just take $T$ to be PA + "PA is inconsistent," and let $\varphi(x)$ be "$x$ is a PA-proof of $0=1$." $T$ can "analyze proofs," and so for any specific term $t$ can check that $t$ does not correspond to a PA-proof of $0=1$. $\quad\Box$

*(Note that the terms here correspond exactly to the standard natural numbers, and a model of PA is nonstandard exactly when it has an element not corresponding to any term.)* The above is an example of [**$\omega$-inconsistency**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-consistent_theory). Note that in order for this to occur, $T$ must have the property that any model of $T$ must have many elements not corresponding to any term.

We can also whip up a slightly less exciting phenomenon in a more natural theory:

> There is a formula $\psi$ such that PA proves $\exists x\psi(x)$ but for no term $t$ does PA prove $\psi(t)$.

(Note that assuming that PA is **sound**, we can't possibly get the stronger phenomenon of PA$\vdash\neg\psi(t)$ for each term $t$.)

*Proof*: Let $\psi(x)$ be the formula "(PA is inconsistent and $x=1$) or (PA is consistent and $x=0$)." Then PA proves $\psi(0)\vee\psi(1)$, but can't prove either $\psi(0)$ or $\psi(1)$ specifically. $\quad\Box$